# colcon build failed for soss-ros1 in soss

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed steps in https://github.com/osrf/soss to run the demo for understanding of SOSS. I have installed both ROS Crystal and Melodic. However, `colcon build`  failed for building `soss-ros1` . I attach the logs. I am unsure what those error messages mean. Can you please help to take a look? Thanks.

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/6c7e8ba775526ee03491a36674402ba9

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355022/colcon-build-failed-for-soss-ros1-in-soss/) by [albertleng](https://answers.ros.org/users/55672/albertleng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After changing from gcc/g++-5 to gcc/g++-7, I can build soss-ros1-test, i.e.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

followed by choosing gcc/g++-7.

However, running

```
soss src/soss-ros1/examples/hello_ros.yaml
```

failed. I will ask question about it in a separate thread.

---

Originally posted by [albertleng](https://answers.ros.org/users/55672/albertleng/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0